# removing a chunk of lines in xml tagged text data using Batch script by the search of id

Tags: xml, batch-file

I want to remove a complete section of XML tag by matching the id :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<messages>
  <note ID="501">
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>
  <note ID="502">
    <to>Jani</to>
    <from>Tove</from>
    <heading>Re: Reminder</heading>
    <body>I will not!</body>
  </note>
```

my batch code is :

```
@ECHO OFF
title Delete Data
echo Press the id that needs to be Deleted
set /p id= 

echo hi

set notepad_program=C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
set notepad_file=C:\Users\shubham1.mishra\Desktop\Employee

cd "%notepad_file%"

rem for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (Edit_sample_xml.txt) do 
rem if %%A equ "502" (type Edit_sample_xml.txt | findstr /v %id% > Xml2.txt %%A)  

type Edit_sample_xml.txt | findstr /v %id% > Xml2.txt


start "%notepad_program%" "Xml2.txt"

pause
```

### exit

My code only removes one line that matches the id but i want to remove complete chunk i.e, full "note" tag having all the data of that particular id.

Comment: You are using the wrong type of script, batch files are not recommended for this type of task. I'd suggest you look at `PowerShell` instead.

Comment: Batch files just process _lines_. You may omit _from_ the line that mathes the id _until_ the closing `</note>` line.

Comment: @Aacini I have been trying to do the same but how exactly am i supposed to do by code.

Comment: You may read the file and just output the lines until find the desired one. After that omit the lines until find the closing one, and then output the lines again until the EOF...